# how to write one sql to update data?

Tags: t-sql, sybase

Suppose I have data in table like:

```
id    level  flag
1     1      0  
1     2      0  
1     3      1  
1     4      0  
1     5      1  
1     6      0  
1     7      0  
1     8      1  
1     9      1  
1     10     0     

2     1      0  
2     2      0  
2     3      0  
2     4      0  
2     5      1  
2     6      1  
2     7      1
```

......

I want to update flag to 0 after first 1 value for flag. For example, with above sample data, 
for id = 1, the first flag value =1 is level=3, then all flag values for level>3 should be updated to 0.

For id = 2, should update flag = 0 for all level>5

How to implement it with sql even one sql statement?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a `WHERE EXISTS` on the same table:

```
UPDATE t1
SET flag = 0
FROM TheTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TheTable t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id
    AND t2.level < t1.level
    AND t2.flag = 1
)
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3094/1)

Comment: thx. it's working but performance is not good. there are more than 10,000,000 rows in this table.

Comment: Try adding an index on (id, flag, level)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an `exists` statement:

```
update table t
    set flag = 0
    where exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        t2.level < t.level and
                        t2.flag = 1
                 );
```